# Illuminate Route with existing url

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am designing a MVC framework for an existing application. I am familiar with Laravel, so I would like to use it components. The problem is with the Route class. The existing application is using url queries in the old way (/file.php?name=aaa&param=1&...) and I want to make something like that:

```
domain.com/file.php?param=1&route=/controller/method/params
```

So as you can see, if I defined the route rule:

```
Route::get('/home/get', 'HomeController@get');
```

it should match to

```
domain.com/file.php?param=1&route=/home/get
```

Is it possible to do without a radically changes of laravel framework (I want to use facades)?

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm stupid or too bias-ed, what is the point of trying to rewrite a SEO-friendly URI to get a SEO-unfriendly URI when it is already rewritten? Look at this: `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php`, url is re-written by removing the `index.php` on path.

I'm uncertain that you can achieve your goals by not modifying any part of Laravel; but if you need, then `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php` should be modified.

Comment: Thank you for your response. No, you are not stupid :) I just want to handle different way the Route class. In this case SEO is unnecessary because it is for a backend. I will try your method tomorrow.

Comment: I modified the UrlGenerator class and url paths look just like I needed but the request handles only the root Route (/). If I have a  route `controller/action` nothings is happening.